# I want to make my function void

Tags: java, function, void

I want to make my function void getScore(), but I want this code to still work correctly. I am trying to figuare out what arguements I need to use and if I an missing any additional code to get this void method to work how I want it to. any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LowestScore {

    int grade;
    static int test1, test2, test3, test4, test5;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        getScore(test1);
        test2 = getScore();
        test3 = getScore();
        test4 = getScore();
        test5 = getScore();
        System.out.print("Test1" +test1);
        System.out.print("Test2" +test2);
        System.out.print("Test3" +test3);
        System.out.print("Test4" +test4);
        System.out.print("Test5" +test5);
    }

    void getScore(){

        Scanner score = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean testNum = false;
        //int grade = 0;
        do{
            try{
                testNum = true;
                System.out.print("Enter in a test grade.");
                grade = score.nextInt();

                if((grade < 0) || (grade > 100)){
                    System.out.print("Invalid Entry. ");
                    testNum = false;

                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.print("What you entered was not a grade. Try again. ");
                testNum = false;
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String clear = score.nextLine();
            }
        }while(!testNum);
        //return;
        //return grade; 
    }
}
```

Comment: `test2 = getScore();` This line is _completely incompatible_ with `getScore()` being a `void` method.  You _cannot_ have `getScore` be a `void` method and have anything like that line work.

Comment: should it be more like the line above it?

Comment: It looks like it should probably be `int getScore()` and it looks like you should `return grade` at the end.

Comment: The void metod will not let me returen a int?

Comment: [Can someone explain a void return type in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689883/can-someone-explain-a-void-return-type-in-java)

Comment: @ShemaMartin No.  You cannot return anything from a void method.

Comment: @ShemaMartin, why do you want your method to have a void return type?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make my function void getScore(), but I want this code to
>   still work correctly.

It is something like *I'll cut legs of a dog but it should still run.*

In that case `int score = getScore()` is not correct *Why?* because your `getScore` method does not return anything now as it's now `void` and you will have compile time error.

You should determine first exactly what your `getScore` should do if it should return the score as name suggest than it must return the score.Using the result of score at caller side is a different concept.Now, if your `getScore` does not return anything than the name is weird for the caller and it should be `calculateScore` or `collectScore` etc.

Comment: Upvote for this sentence: "I'll cut legs of a dog but it should still run.".. Method name is getScore() but it  should not return score ;-)